# Test an if condition with mockito

Tags: java

Code of the if statement:

```
if (reponse.getStatus() >= HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST) {
                LOGGER.error("Erreur lors de l'enregistrement de la trace technique - {}", reponse.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase());
            }
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: please add explanation, what error did you get, so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Basically testing always consists of two parts:

- *preparing* some input, so that your production code under test takes a specific path
- verifying that the expected "things" happened

First one is easy: you have to *somehow* make sure that the `response` object that your production code is dealing with has the required status. How you do that, very much depends on context.

For the second aspect, that is probably *hard*. You see, the only action taking place is a (probably static) call to that `error()` message. If that is the case, then your only way of testing this would be to use JMockit or PowerMock(ito), because those two frameworks allow you to verify `static` method calls.

So, the real answer is:

- figure for yourself how you can gain control over that `response` object
- buy into using one of these mocking frameworks (not recommended)
- rework your code so that it becomes testable without adding that (imho really really bad) dependency towards PowerMock(ito).

Comment: If this is the actual code, rather than a condensation for SO, one could say that something so trivial doesn't need a unit test.  "If one number bigger than another number, log a message" is pretty straightforward, assuming ```getStatus()``` is already tested to return good values.

Comment: @another-dave Depends where you are coming from. When you do TDD, anything that happens has a test. And note: even such simple things as logging something ... can go wrong. What if that response is *somehow* invalid and maybe `reponse.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase()` leads to an NPE? A test might have prevent a runtime error. Beyond that: today, you go "this code is so simple, I dont need a test for it". Tomorrow, you have to enhance it, and it is still simple. So no test. And in three weeks, when you *really* have to make a change ... then you dont have a test you can rely on.